# how to compare tuples of string in python?

Tags: python

Is there any way to do following task in python?, i have a 2 or more tuples of string in python in that sometimes 1st string is different and all others are the same so I want output like the following-

```
a1=[('1','a','b','3'),('2','a','b','3')]
# yields ['1','2']

a2=[('23','j','k','l'),('2','j','k','l'), ('34','j','k','l')]
# yields ['23','2','34']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip` for this. Default result is tuple, so we convert back to list via `map`.

```
a1 = [('1','a','b','3'), ('2','a','b','3')]

res = next(map(list, zip(*a1)))

# ['1', '2']

res2 = next(map(list, zip(*a2)))

# ['23', '2', '34']
```

Comment: `next(...)` instead of `list(...)[0]`

Comment: Thank You so much

Comment: But, this does not check if other elements in the tuple are being matched each other. - what if the list is something like [('1','a','b','3'),('2','b','c','4')] ?